# Update a value inside document using document's value in findOneAndUpdateQuery- Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user scheme like this

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  { 
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    points: Number
}
```

I want to update the user's points using the current user's points i.e **user.points += 100**
or like this In query

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate( userId , 
      { loyaltyPoints :  user.loyaltyPoints + 100}
      , {new  :true, runValidator :true} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since points is a number, you can use MongoDB [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) which is specifically design for this purpose. So a `+= 100` would be

```
{
  $inc: {
    points: 100
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man It solved my problem ,

Comment: But I faced 1 problem, I have a base scheme User and a discriminator of User which was "Visitor", and loyaltyPoints was in Visitor so my time got wasted in User.findOneAndUpdate instead of Visitor.findOneAndUpdate